# Rails 4 + Postgresql - Joins table with 2 conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, scope

I need to list `Inputs` that have `Translations` with `language_id = 1` **and dont have Translations with `language_id = 2`**

My current scope is:

```
scope :language, -> (id){joins(:translations).where('translations.language_id = 1)}
```

Models:

```
class Input < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :translations
  has_many :languages, through: :translations
  scope :language, -> (id) {joins(:translations).where('translations.language_id = 1')}

  def translation_from_language(language)
    self.translations.where(language: language).take
  end
end

class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :input
  belongs_to :language
  before_save :default_values

  #Apenas para testar o scope de search
  scope :search, -> (part) { where("LOWER(value) LIKE ?", "%#{part.downcase}%") }

  # Se nao setar um input manualmente, irá criar um novo
  def default_values
    self.input ||= Input.create
  end
end

class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :translations
  has_many :inputs, through: :translations
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my solution is just create a query like

```
Input.where("id IN ( SELECT input_id
                     FROM translations
                     WHERE language_id = 1
                   )
             AND id NOT IN (
                     SELECT input_id
                     FROM translations
                     WHERE language_id = 2
                   )")
```

Comment: The problem here is that the second where is useless, because if the row have language_id = 1, necesseraly dont have the language_id = 2. I think we need to use subqueries, but I dont know how.

Comment: You want to query the input with all tranlations which have language_id = 1?

Comment: I need to list the Inputs that have a translations associated to the input with language_id = 1, but dont have translations associated to the input with language_id = 2

Comment: Didn't work, still querying inputs with translations from both languages

Comment: Hmm, let me try, try to check my update, I think it works now

Comment: I think we are almost there. Now the query returns empty.

Comment: Changing the != to = works perfectly!
Thank you very much!
Please edit your awnser to the right one.